# Autohotkey string evaluation / comparison not working as expected

Tags: autohotkey

```
category_generic = book, book_asl, author, author_asl, publisher
StringSplit, categories_array, category_generic, `,
Loop 
{
    category := categories_array%a_index%
    do_my_amazing_stuff
    if (category = "author")
    {
        do_some_more_amazing_stuff
    }
}
```

Problem: The evaluation: if (category = "author") never holds true, despite the fact that the loop parses through the entire content of the array. Moreover, it can write out the categories correctly as they appear in the array, out to a file. I tried billion different versions, none of it works. Can someone explain to me why the evaluation does not get evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the spaces in your list. AHK won't magically drop them. If you look closely, the spaces after each list item appear in your output file, too. Either leave them out in the first place or discard them in some way. `StringSplit` provides such a functionality with `OmitChars`:

```
StringSplit, categories_array, category_generic, `, %A_SPACE%
```